# How to calculate np.cov on a matrix with np.nan values without converting to pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, covariance

I have the following `np.array`:

```
my_matrix = np.array([[1,np.nan,3], [np.nan,1,2], [np.nan,1,2]])
```

```
array([[ 1., nan,  3.],
       [nan,  1.,  2.],
       [nan,  1.,  2.]])
```

If I evaluate `np.cov` on it, I get:

```
np.cov(my_matrix)
```

```
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan]])
```

But if I were to calculate it with `pd.DataFrame.cov` I get a different result:

```
pd.DataFrame(my_matrix).cov()
```

```
    0   1   2
0   NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 0.0 0.000000
2   NaN 0.0 0.333333
```

I know that as per [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html) documentation, they handle `nan` values.

My question is, how can I get the same (or similar result) with `numpy`? Or how to handle missing data when calculating covariance with `numpy`?

Comment: According to this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100945/how-to-calculate-variance-covariance-matrix-of-a-matrix the NumPy solution is correct. Perhaps the Pandas computation refers to something different?

Comment: They both are "correct". The pandas one managed to handle nan and missing values though and I would like to manage to do that as well with numpy, but don't know how.

Comment: According to IEEE, any operation with NaN has to give NaN as result. If you work out the equation, a NaN is involved on all entries of the cov matrix. Of course, you could replace NaN with a number that would let you move forward with the computation. That is not the cov matrix of the original input though. Try to replace NaN with 0 or a large number (e.g. 1e20) and you will likely get pandas's approximation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of Numpy's [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/maskedarray.html).

```
import numpy.ma as ma
cv = ma.cov(ma.masked_invalid(my_matrix), rowvar=False)
cv
```

```
masked_array(
  data=[[--, --, --],
        [--, 0.0, 0.0],
        [--, 0.0, 0.33333333333333337]],
  mask=[[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

To produce an `ndarray` with `nan` values filled in, use the `filled` method.

```
cv.filled(np.nan)
```

```
array([[       nan,        nan,        nan],
       [       nan, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [       nan, 0.        , 0.33333333]])
```

---

Note that `np.cov` produces pairwise row covariances by default. To replicate Pandas behavior (pairwise column covariances), you must pass `rowvar=False` to `ma.cov`.